# How to append array key and value into another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to push a new array key and value into the exiting array. Therefore, I use `array_push` to append the data.

Code

```
$account_no = $acc_no['bank']['account_no'];
$new_account_no = [
                    $model->id => Input::get('account_no'),//This result is "32" => "1234562"
                  ];
array_push($account_no, $new_account_no);
```

Result

```
"bank": {
      "account_no": {
        "23": "1111111111",
        "24": {
          "32": "1234562"
        }
      }
    }
```

So now the problem is, the array data I pushed added a key `24` which is incorrect and it suppose only push `"32": "1234562"`

Expected result

```
"bank": {
          "account_no": {
            "23": "1111111111",
            "32": "1234562" 
          }
        }
```

Comment: just directly assign it, no need for any functions, `$acc_no['bank']['account_no'][id here] = value here`

Answer (score 0):

$account_no[$model->id] = Input::get('account_no');